# Possible to change UISlider's button size in iOS5?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uislider

Time for another iOS question.

Just wondering if it is possible programmatically to change the radius of the slider's control button. I want to make the control bigger or smaller to represent the brush size that it is selecting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
Assigns a thumb image to the specified control states:
- (void)setThumbImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```